# Using a C# class from a managed C++ project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr, managed-c++

I have a solution with a managed C++ project and a C# project. The C# project is a class library project containing the GUI classes I use from the C++ project. This works well, but building results in two DLLs.

Is there a way of using the C# objects from the C++ project without having a dynamically linked library generated by the C# project (is there a way to embed the C# types into the managed C++ project)?

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but it is far outside the tooling you are using to be able to accomplish it.

[You can use command line tooling to create a multi netmodule assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe(v=vs.110).aspx).

Managed assemblies are built of one or more "netmodules". Typically in a C# project, there is only one netmodule, and the C# compiler builds it and then links it into the assembly it produces. By using the command line tools, you can build only a module, then link it with the C++ module into an assembly.